# Java - Stop a thread automatically when program ends

Tags: java, multithreading

Take a look at this code:

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    //some code here
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("End of main");
    }

}
```

Normally, when the end of `main` is reached, the program terminates. But in this example, the program will prints "End of main" and then keeps running because the thread is still running. Is there a way that the thread can stop *automatically* when the end is reached, without using something like `while(isRunning)`?

Comment: Have you really verified what you claim?

Comment: @narush yes I verified it. It's what's happening to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thread you are creating is independent and does not depend on the Main Thread termination. You can use `Daemon` thread for the same. **Daemon threads will be terminated by the JVM when there are none of the other non- daemon threads running, it includes a main thread of execution as well.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Daemon thread");
            }
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();

    System.out.println("End of main");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it [a daemon thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)).

> `public final void setDaemon(boolean on)`
> Marks this thread as either a
>   daemon thread or a user thread. **The Java Virtual Machine exits when
>   the only threads running are all daemon threads**. This method must be
>   invoked before the thread is started.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
});

t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();

System.out.println("End of main");
```